# How to delete the file after 30 seconds/ or delete the file once after the job is completed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, delete-file

I am working on a C# project and i need the file to deleted after 30 seconds. So once the file sent to the machine i need the software to count till 30 seconds and at same time **show a splash form** and once 30 seconds crossed close the splash screen and then delete the file.

**I have added a splash screen called "image". So now what happens is, the data is only sent to the printer after the splash screen is closed.  I need to multi thread the job. I mean the data should print in one side while the splash screen should show at the same time. Is there a way i can come out!!.. Please help me out.**

So in my case i am copying the file to the bin/debug folder. then sending data to the machine simultaneously show the splash screen  for 30 seconds and close the splash screen and then i need to delete the file..

codes:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string filePath = image_print();
       // MessageBox.Show(filePath, "path");
        string s = image_print() + Print_image();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || img_path.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
         //here its coming to the splash screen code, But data is transferred to the machine only after the splash screen is close :-(
           this.Hide();
        omg = new image();
        omg.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
         //splash screen closed and then data is transferred.. which i don't need.. i need simultaneous job to be done at the same time..
         PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);
        }
    }

    private string image_print()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string path = "";
        string full_path = "";
        string filename_noext = "";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\ZTOOLS\FONTS";
        ofd.Filter = "GRF files (*.grf)|*.grf";
        ofd.FilterIndex = 2;
        ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename_noext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
            path = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
            img_path.Text = filename_noext;
            //MessageBox.Show(filename_noext, "Filename"); - - -> switching.grf
            // MessageBox.Show(full_path, "path");
            //move file from location to debug
            string replacepath = @"\\bin\Debug";
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
            string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(replacepath, fileName);
           // string newpath = string.Empty;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename_noext))
                System.IO.File.Copy(path, newpath);
            filename_noext = img_path.Text;
         MessageBox.Show(filename_noext, "path");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(img_path.Text))
            return "";//

        StreamReader test2 = new StreamReader(img_path.Text);
        string s = test2.ReadToEnd();
        return s;
    }


    private string Print_image()
    {
        //some codes
            return s;
    }
```

In **image form: I have the following codes**

```
public partial class image : Form
{
    string filePath;
    public image()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // this.filePath = FileToDeletePath;

        System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 30000;
        timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void image_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //delete the file using "filePath"
        string Filename = img_path.Text; // here i cannot pass the old string file name with  extension to this form.. Any ways please help me out

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename))
            return;

        if (Filename.ToCharArray().Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Any())
            return;

        File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"\\bin\Debug", Filename));
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that it looks way to close to copy-paste of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618555/how-to-delete-the-file-after-30-seconds). At very least make sure to provide attribution to author of the second half of the code and explain how this question is significantly different.

Comment: You talk about sending the file to a machine, and then out of nowhere you talk about a printer. I'm confused. Why is this file going to the machine? When's it being printed? What is the splash screen for? Is it on your machine or the machine receiving the file?

Comment: given both solutions are correct, u can use any one of them. But, I know u are getting trouble to implement it. Second thing you don't need to use `ShowDialog()` method here. you can use `Show()` method instead. After this line you just need to call sleep method from threading class and give the interval in millisecond. Application will be stop for given interval in millisecond then it will continue back. Now, after sleep method you can write code to delete the file and at the and u can close the splash window by calling `omg.Close()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by *Narzul* and *Peter* both are correct. You can implement any one. But, I know your next question will be how to implement that method in your code.

you can use `Thread` or `Task` class object to separate the process. So when one process is running then other process can perform their taks at that time. There are two process in your login. The first one is send the file to the printer and the second one is the show dialog for 30 seconds and then delete the file. You should create the another thread to invoke the any one of the process so other process can perform asynchronously.

**1st:** make the seperate process for Print file.

```
Task waitfordelete = Task.Run(() =>
{
    PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);
});

this.Hide();
omg = new image();
omg.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

**2nd:** make the seperate process for show dialog and delete the file. But, I think you may get the error in this method. *You cannot change the UI from other thread*

```
Task waitfordelete = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.ShowSplashScreen());
});

PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);


private void ShowSplashScreen()
{
    this.Hide();
    omg = new image(); 
    omg.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();        
}
```

---

if you don't want to use the thread or task then just simply handle the close event of `Image` form

```
this.Hide();
omg = new image(); 
omg.Show();
PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);
omg.FormClosed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Path.GetFileName(img_path.Text));
    this.Show();    
};
```

and modify the code in `timer_tick` event in `Image` form and add the `this.Close()` after delete file statement.

```
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    //File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"\\bin\Debug", Filename)); comment this line
    this.Close();
}
```

---

Another hidden question I have found here. *here i cannot pass the old string file name with  extension to this form.. Any ways please help me out*

```
 void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //delete the file using "filePath"
    string Filename = img_path.Text; // here i cannot pass the old string file name with  extension to this form.. Any ways please help me out
```

for that, you can create the property in Image class and assign the file name from the parent form.

```
Image omg = new Image()
omg.FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Path.GetFileName(img_path.Text));
omg.Show();
```

and the property in Image form will be created like this

```
public class Image : Form
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public Image()
    {
    }

    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, this.Filename));
        this.Close();
    }        
}
```

**NOTE: Use the `Application.StartupPath` istead of `\\bin\debug`**

Comment: thanks a lot.. but i am getting error in all the lines :-( in line `ask waitfordelete = Task.Run(() =>` its asking me for do you want to create a class for task it seems!!

Comment: in this line its asking `(object sender, EventArgs e) => (File.Delete(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Path.GetFileName(img_path.Text))));` does not meet delegate parameters type

Answer (score 2):

something like this????

```
Task waitfordelete = Task.Run(() =>
{
    image im = new image();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions: window `image` should be shown as a dialog (modal), and only while the call to `PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1` is in progress.

If that's correct, then something like this could work for you:

```
// Don't forget, you need to dispose modal dialogs
image omg = new image();

// Ensure the dialog has been shown before starting task. That
// way the task knows for sure the dialog's been opened and can
// be closed.
omg.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Run the print task in a separate task
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        PrintFactory.sendTextToLPT1(s);
        // But get back onto the main GUI thread to close the dialog
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => omg.Close());
    });
};

this.Hide();
omg.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Apologies in advance for any typos/syntax errors/etc. Hopefully the above is sufficient to express the general idea.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't now how to implement this... its showing me many errors... :P

Comment: I know of a couple of typos that existed in my original edit, but they have been fixed as of yesterday. Are you working with the latest version of the answer? If so, you will need to be more specific than "many errors".